# What parent is viewContext referring to, when viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent set to true?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

It is common to have background context to perform write operation.

```
// Set automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent to true
persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { backgroundcontext in
    // Do your work...
    let object = backgroundContext.object(with: restaurant.objectID)
    backgroundContext.delete(object)
    // Save changes to persistent store, update viewContext and notify fetched results controller
    try? backgroundContext.save()
}
```

I am confused on the `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent`.

As, I have the following observation on `viewContext` (The managed object context associated with the main queue) and `backgroundContext`.

1. `viewContext.parent` is nil
2. `backgroundContext.parent` is nil

My questions are

1. If we need to set `viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true`, in order for `viewContext` to receive changes from `backgroundContext`, does that mean `backgroundContext` is the parent of `viewContext`?
2. If not, what parent is `viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the parent is nil, it's nil, there's no implicit parent relationship. When the parent context is nil, `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` automatically merges changes saved to its persistent store coordinator. It's not a parent context but it does some parent context-like things here. As long as the two contexts use the same persistent store coordinator (or the same `NSPersistentContainer`) then this will automatically merge changes without a parent context relationship.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` in such case imply `viewContext` is getting latest change from persistent store coordinator, and not parent contenxt. Perhaps if they have a verbose naming like `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParentOrPersistentStoreCoordinator` will make the thing clear ;-)